# If $\{{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges then $\{{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_k}^2\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove or disprove:

a. If $\bigg\{{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\bigg\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges then $\bigg\{{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_k}^2\bigg\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges.

b. If $\bigg\{{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_k}^2\bigg\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges then $\bigg\{{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_k}\bigg\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges.

I tried solving both with no success. At first I thought that they are both to be contradicted. Then I thought that only b. is to be contradicted.

**EDIT: THERE ARE NO FINAL ANSWERS**

Comment: Hint: try $x_k = (-1)^k \ln k$.

Comment: Other hint: try $x_k = (-1)^{\lfloor \ln k \rfloor}$.

Answer (score 3):

Both are false.

For (a): take $x_{n^2} = n^{2/3}$. Then:

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n^2} x_k = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^{2/3} \leq\sim n^{-1/3},$$

but:

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n^2} x_k^2 = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^{4/3} \geq\sim n^{2/3},$$

so the first converges to $0$ and the second diverges.

For (b), Siméon's comment is perfect: take $x_k = (-1)^{\lfloor \ln (k) \rfloor}$. Then $x_k^2 = 1$ for all $k$, but the Cesaro average of the $x_k$ will asymptotically oscillate, if I didn't make any mistake, between $\frac{e-1}{e(1+e)}$ and $-\frac{e-1}{e(1+e)}$ (you can quite easily get worse lower bounds on the oscillations, such as $1-\frac{2}{e}$ and $\frac{2}{e}-1$).

Comment: What did you write ${1\over n^2}$ out of the sum? 
I thought it has to remain ${1\over n}$...

Comment: @Meitar: because I only look at the sums at the times 1, 4, 9, 16, etc. There is still a little (boring) work to do.